# How to use curly braces over multiple lines?

Tags: braces

I would like to typeset a multi-line set.

### I want to typeset something similar to this image:

[image]

I have tried using an `equation` environment and an `align` environment but to no avail.

### Attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}




\newcommand{\f}[1]{\includegraphics[width=2em,valign=c]{#1}}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \left\{\f{example-image-a},\f{example-image-a},\f{example-image-a}\\
        ,\f{example-image-a}  ,\f{example-image-a}  ,\f{example-image-a}\right\}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

The right brace: `\right\}` disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to give the `\left.` `\right.` below is the modified `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}




\newcommand{\f}[1]{\includegraphics[width=2em,valign=c]{#1}}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \left\{\f{example-image-a},\f{example-image-a},\f{example-image-a}\right.\\
\left.        ,\f{example-image-a}  ,\f{example-image-a}  ,\f{example-image-a}\right\}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

with use of `array` and `\Bigl\{`, \Bigr} delimiters:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\f}[1]{\includegraphics[width=3em,valign=c]{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \[\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
    \begin{array}{*{9}{l}}
\Bigl\{ & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, 
        & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, 
        & \f{example-image-duck}, &  \\[2ex]
        & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck},
        & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck},
        & \f{example-image-duck}, & \\[2ex]
        & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck},
        & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck},
        & \f{example-image-duck}, & \\[2ex]
        & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck},
        & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck}, & \f{example-image-duck},
        & \f{example-image-duck}  & \Bigr\}
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```